# Fork join with multiple return types

Tags: rxjs

```js
Observable.forkJoin(
  request1(),
  request2(),
  request3().subscribe(result =>{
    //do something
  })
);
```

In the above code:

- `request1` returns `Observable<{ [key: string]: string; }>`
- `request2` returns `Observable<{ [key: string]: { [key: string]: string; }; }>`.

The error message is:

> Argument of type 'Observable<{ [key:    string]: string; }>' is not
>   assignable to parameter of type    'ObservableInput<{ [key: string]: {
>   [key: string]: string; }; }>'.

Could someone help me solve the problem?

Comment: Hey can you show your code inside your subscribe? When using `forkJoin` you are subscribing to an array. So you `result` variable is actually an array and you are probably messing with the value types inside it. Also be careful to close your `forkJoin()` before subscribing to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

Import **forkjoin** first.

```
import {forkJoin} from 'rxjs';

return forkJoin( this.http.get('path/api'), this.http.get('path/api2'));
```

It will return data in array form.

Comment: @Teja so you forgot to import `forkJoin`? From the error message I got a different impression.

Comment: I was using  import { Observable } from 'rxjs'; when I changed it to import {forkJoin} from 'rxjs'; it worked

Answer (score 2):

You're passing a `Subscription` as the third argument to `forkJoin`. Probably you want to write the following:

```
Observable.forkJoin(request1(), request2(), request3()).subscribe(result =>{
    //do something
});
```